# How to find values that fit a certain criteria in python3

Tags: python, math

so I am a beginner at python and I just had my specialist math exam today and the last question on the paper made me think about how I can find the answer using python. part of the question was to find 3 values between 0-9 like a pin sorta and the sum of the 3 values must be greater than the product of the 3 numbers. e.g. 1+1+1 > 1x1x1. I cant seem to figure how to write this in python to find all values or the number of combinations of values. I have thought about trying a while or for loop but cant figure out how to test all the different values. I know this question is math related but I want to find every value that works for the criteria. Possibly push the values that work into an array and print the array once complete.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, but it sounds like a math question rather than a programming question. The computer can only follow the steps you give it; it can't determine what steps to follow.

Comment: this is a math question check this answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16684/when-is-the-product-of-a-set-of-numbers-greater-than-the-sum-of-them

Comment: pretty much i want to find what 3 values between 0-9 (inclusive) fit the criteria of the sum of the 3 numbers being greater than the product of all 3 numbers. like 1+1+1 =3 is greater than 1x1x1 which is 1. i want to find all values that work like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might harness [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this task following way:

```
import itertools
values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for x,y,z in itertools.product(values, repeat=3):
    if(x+y+z > x*y*z):
        print(x,y,z)
```

output:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 1 4
1 1 5
1 1 6
1 1 7
1 1 8
1 1 9
1 2 1
1 2 2
1 3 1
1 4 1
1 5 1
1 6 1
1 7 1
1 8 1
1 9 1
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 2 1
3 1 1
4 1 1
5 1 1
6 1 1
7 1 1
8 1 1
9 1 1
```

Note: I did not include `0` in values. Explanation: `itertools.product` works like odometer, so for example if `values` would be `[0,1]` then it would check: `0,0,0` then `0,0,1` then `0,1,0` then `0,1,1` then `1,0,0` then `1,0,1` then `1,1,0` then `1,1,1`. This is equivalent of nesting three loops.

Comment: Thanks heaps this is exactly what i was after, i added 0 to the values list and made a variable that counts all the values. turns out i think i was close to the right answer in my exam. but thanks heaps